How to connect SQL Server via node-mssql?
Below is my typescript code, it uses node's mssql library to connect to my SQL Server database, but I got an error.
Below is code example:
import * as sql from 'mssql'

  // just  code snippet here ....
  console.log('sqlConfig ->', sqlConfig)
  let pool: sql.ConnectionPool | null = null
  try {
    pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig).connect()
    // Query the database
    const result = await pool.query`
    SELECT id, givenname, familyname, employeeId, insert_date
    FROM emp
    WHERE employeeId = ${employeeId}`

    pool.close()

    console.log('### result.recordset ###-> ', result.recordset)

    return result.recordset
  }

Error

An error occurred while connecting to the database: TypeError: sql.ConnectionPool is not a constructor


You are trying to call .connect() on sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig).
The problem is that it is asynchronous, so the .connect() function is not available until the promise is finished.
You can fix this in one of two ways:

Wrap the await in parenthesis like this:
(await new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig)).connect()

Only call .connect() on a seperate line:
pool = await new sql.ConnectionPool(sqlConfig); pool.connect()


See here.

I tried option 2,  got error TypeError: sql.ConnectionPool is not a constructor

here are libs i am using  "mssql": "^10.0.2",
"@types/mssql": "^9.1.5",

i used knex +mssql, then it works
